# Passing anonymous type variables as method parameters

Tags: c#, types, anonymous

I have two class of A & B, I want to pass var type variable by a method `Separation()` that is in another class. I do some casting but I receive `InvalidCastException` error. Any idea how to fix this, please?

```
Class A{
       var products =from u in XDoc.Descendants("product")
            select new
            {
                Urunkod = u.Element("productId"),
                                UrunAdi = u.Element("title"),
            };

         XmlUrun.Separate(products);
       }

Class B{
            internal static void Separate(object products)
            {
                var o2 = CaseByExample(products, new
                {
                    Urunkod = "",
                    UrunAdi = "",
                });
            }
            public static T CaseByExample<T>(this object o, T type)
            {
                return (T)o;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This would be a good example of when to use `dynamic` types???

Comment: I don't believe you can do that using anonymous lists.  Perhaps you could create a DTO class to contain your productId and title values?

Comment: @dreza: I think that a DTO would be a better idea. Much better for type-safety!

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous type cannot be passed in a strong manner outside the scope of an individual method, because there is no way to represent it outside the method's scope.

You can either use a `dynamic` type (which I don't recommend), or create a named class to represent the type (which I do recommend).

```
public class A
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        var products =from u in XDoc.Descendants("product")
        select new C
        {
            Urunkod = u.Element("productId"),
                            UrunAdi = u.Element("title"),
        };
    }
}

public class B
{
    public void Bar(IEnumerable<C> cList)
    {
        foreach(var c in cList)
            Console.WriteLine(c.Urunkod);
    }
}

public class C
{
    public XElement Urunkod {get;set;}
    public XElement Urunkadi {get;set;}
}
```